# Solving a pair of recurrence relations

Tags: equation-solving, recursion

Why does this

```
RSolve[{y[t] == a*y[t - 1]}, {y[t]}, t]
```

work, while this

```
RSolve[{y[t] == a[t - 1]*y[t - 1], a[t] == a[t - 1]}, {y[t], a[t]}, t]
```

does not given any interesting result?

---

My goal is to solve something of the kind:

```
RSolve[{y[t] == function[y[t - 1],a[t-1]], a[t] == b*a[t - 1]}, {y[t], a[t]}, t]
```

Comment: If the equation for `a[t]` is decoupled from the rest, can't you solve it first and then use the solution in the equation for `y[t]` ?

Comment: @b.gatessucks Yes that's indeed a solution! Thank you!